# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlcipher3'" error while using Python 3.7 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysqlcipher

I am trying to decrypt one database file using Python 3.7. To decrypt it, I have to use `pysqlcipher3` version for python 3.7. To install it, I have tried by using both commands:

```
pip3 install pysqlcipher3
```

and

```
pip install pysqlcipher3
```

and both the commands have showed successful installation of the `pysqlcipher` package. However, when I try to import `pysqlcipher3` in my Python project by using this line:

```
from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

it displays this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlcipher3
```

I have checked various GitHub projects, but none of them provide a clear working solution. The Python packages website says to install `libsqlcipher` in your OS but this time the issue is same, no documentation and link regarding for the installation of `libsqlcipher` for Windows 10. Can anyone provide me with proper installation steps, or any document, or any video tutorial, regarding the same? Or is there some issue with the import statement?

Comment: It is likely that your environment has two Python installations and the version of `pip.exe` that you called is the one for the environment you don't expect. Navigate to the folder under `Python37` where `pip.exe` is installed (in Windows it is in `Scripts`) and run it from there.

Comment: Make sure you used relevant pip (can run: `which pip`) with the python interpeter you are using

Comment: @Aaron_ab I have previously tried by installing many other packages using pip from cmd and they work fine.

Comment: @TheOnionMaster Well i uninstalled everything and installed it by using pip3, it worked but still not able to  decrypt the db.Its a very complicated process for windows and was not that worth to spend time upon plus there is not any single complete guide to do this so you need to collect data from various sources.

Comment: What is the name of your python file?

Comment: https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=01250-01c021e8-a341-46b5-a304-ddb1e75e5796

Comment: This is very common question and I gave a pretty extensive answer a while ago. Maybe it is helpful for your case as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451612/10669875

Comment: refer here for windows installation : https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3/issues/21

Answer (score 1):

You need to install de library `libsqlcipher-dev` from your repository manager, for example:

`sudo apt install libsqlcipher-dev`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3
$ cd sqlcipher3
$ python setup.py build  # Build against the system libsqlcipher
$ sudo python setup.py install
$ cd ..
```

Then enter a Python prompt and try:

```py
from sqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlcipher
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have multiple pip installations by using
`where pip`

Also, check the interpreter being used in your project. Make sure it matches the python interpreter corresponding to the pip installation where the module was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install `libsqlcipher`  from source.

From https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

> **Using MSVC**
>
> On Windows, all applicable build products can be compiled with MSVC.
> First open the command prompt window associated with the desired
> compiler version (e.g. "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013"). Next,
> use NMAKE with the provided "Makefile.msc" to build one of the
> supported targets.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> mkdir bld
> cd bld
> nmake /f Makefile.msc TOP=..\sqlite
> nmake /f Makefile.msc sqlite3.c TOP=..\sqlite
> nmake /f Makefile.msc sqlite3.dll TOP=..\sqlite
> nmake /f Makefile.msc sqlite3.exe TOP=..\sqlite
> nmake /f Makefile.msc test TOP=..\sqlite
> ```
>
> There are several build options that can be set via the NMAKE command
> line. For example, to build for WinRT, simply add "FOR_WINRT=1"
> argument to the "sqlite3.dll" command line above. When debugging into
> the SQLite code, adding the "DEBUG=1" argument to one of the above
> command lines is recommended.
>
> SQLite does not require Tcl to run, but a Tcl installation is required
> by the makefiles (including those for MSVC). SQLite contains a lot of
> generated code and Tcl is used to do much of that code generation.

Answer (score 0):

go checkout where your pip from by using `pip -V`, it outputs the pip path to you.

Check if this path is in the `venv` you want. If not, the package was installed in a wrong path.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have multiple python versions installed on your Operating System. Also if you are using a virtual environment you should activate that before installing any packages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30813329)

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to install sqlcipher and the python library pysqlcipher3 with something like:

```
brew install sqlcipher
pip3 install pysqlcipher3 --user
```